# How to calculate the gauss map of a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to calculate the gauss map for a sphere {$x^2+y^2+z^2=r$}.

To get the upper half sphere I chose the parametrization
$\alpha(x,y)= \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ \sqrt{r-x^2-y^2} \end{array}\right)$
and for the lower half spehre I chose:
$\beta(x,y)= \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ -\sqrt{r-x^2-y^2} \end{array}\right)$

The gauss map N is defined as
$N(x,y)=\frac{\frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial y}}{||\frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial y}||}$

Doing the calculations i get:
$\frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial x}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-x}{\sqrt{r-x^2-y^2}} \end{array}\right)$

and

$\frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial y}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ \frac{-y}{\sqrt{r-x^2-y^2}} \end{array}\right)$

thus,
$N(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{x}{\sqrt{r-x^2-y^2}} \\ \frac{y}{\sqrt{r-x^2-y^2}} \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$ for the upper half of the sphere.

Now my Question:
The way I calculated the gauss map seems not to be the best solution, because if I calculate the gauss map for the upper half sphere $N_u$ and for the lower half sphere $N_l$, how do I differentiate it? Is there a better way of calculating the gauss map (such that one can easily differentiate it)?

Comment: As far as I see the calculation is correct. For **each** parametrization you would get a specific expression for the Gauss map as it depends on the coordinates chosen. In this case, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ yield the exact same formulas for the Gauss map $N_\alpha(x,y)$ and $N_\beta(x,y)$ but that is just a lucky coincidence.

Comment: Do you really need to compute this in local charts? Because the Gauss map of the sphere of radius $r$ is just given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto \frac{1}{r}(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Didier In the exercise, the sphere was given as a equation. Thats why I chose the local charts. Could you show me how to get to your result? Visually it seems obvious but I don't know how to get to your result.

Comment: You have to show that the tangent space of the sphere at a point $p=(x,y,z)$ is the linear subspace $T_pS = p^{\perp}$. Then, it is clear that $\frac{1}{r}(x,y,z)$ is normal to $T_pS$, and of unit length. It is thus the unit normal. It points outward of the sphere.